# Query values in multiple document using "IN" in gcp datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I have following documents in gcp datastore:

```
Kind: "User"
{name: "jay", age: 24, key: Key(["User", 1])}
{name: "jet", age: 35, key: Key(["User", 2])}
{name: "sam", age: 28, key: Key(["User", 3])}
```

Using node sdk for gcp datastore I want to query users with keys: `Key(["User", 1]) & Key(["User", 2])`

I am using following query for the same:

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = new Datastore();
const key1 = datastore.key(["User", 1]);
const key2 = datastore.key(["User", 2]);
const query = datastore.createQuery("User").filter('__key__', 'IN', [key1, key2]);
```

On running the above query using following code:

```
datastore.runQuery(query)
.then(users => {
  console.log(users)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am getting following error:

```
InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind.
```

But the keys already contain the kind "User".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-lookup-nodejs) (look for 'You can look up multiple entities'), you should try this instead

```
    const [users] = await datastore.get([key1, key2]);
    console.log(users)
```